# How do you do a 2d Fourier transform using OpenCV?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I am new to image processing but would like to know how to do a simple 2D Fourier transform on an image using OpenCV?

I am basically looking to do what this Java applet does http://www.brainflux.org/java/classes/FFT2DApplet.html only with OpenCv - I would like a complete example if possible `doDFT(Mat imagein, Mat result)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a complete example of 2d DFT using OpenCV in the official documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html#discretfouriertransform